# Use nullable instead of Option?

Tags: scala

I have singleton:

```
class MySing private (var1: SomeType) { ... }
object MySing {

  @volatile
  private var instance: Option[MySing] = None

  def apply(var1: SomeType): Option[MySing] = {
    if (instance.isEmpty) {
      this.synchronized {
        if (instance.isEmpty) instance = Some(new MySing(var1))
      }
    }

    instance
  }
}
```

So whenever I want to get an instance of it, I have to use either get or pattern matching

```
MySing(myVar1) match {
  case Some(x) => ...
  case None =>
}
```

or

```
MySing(myVar1).get
```

Even Scala encourages using Option, won't it be reasonable in my case not to use it to get rid of boring, redundant operations I've shown above?

```
object MySing {

  @volatile
  private var instance: MySing = null

  def apply(var1: SomeType): MySing = {
    if (instance == null) {
      this.synchronized {
        if (instance == null) instance = new MySing(var1)
      }
    }

    instance
  }
}
```

Comment: Eww. `null`. A terrible perpetuated idea. If only there wasn't such a concept in Scala! I prefer the clarity and "forced" usage an Option type brings.

Comment: There `var` is also useless (`object` is singleton, `lazy val` can be used for lazily init'ed value).

Comment: As @applicius said, you are basically creating a `lazy val` situation, but accepting an argument `var1` that is thrown away if the instance is already initialised. I would really rethink the whole design...

Comment: @applicius, show an example with lazy val and one argument.

Comment: `lazy val` cannot take parameters directly. In this case, `var1` is used as a parameter for initialization. I think this is not that easy case to use `lazy val`.

Comment: I think the variable `instance` should be `Option[MySing]`, and `apply(var1)` should be `MySing`. The only return statement is `instance` at the end of the method, and `instance` cannot be `null` at that return moment, so you can just return `instance.get`.

Comment: @Naetmul, I agree but applicius doesn't.

Comment: The var is used as instance is init'ed later, which is what can be done with lazy val. Moreover instance seems to be there for singleton pattern, but Scala object is automatic singleton. The whole design could be reviewed

Answer (score 2):

Returning `Option[MySing]` implies that you may not return a value (i.e. returning `None`) from `apply`, but I don't see how this makes sense. You are always returning an instance from apply, so you can get ride of the `Option` in the return type, with something like this

```
class MySing private (val var1: String)
object MySing {

  @volatile
  private var instance: Option[MySing] = None

  def apply(var1: String): MySing = {
    instance getOrElse {
      this.synchronized {
        instance.getOrElse {
         instance = Some(new MySing(var1))
         instance.get
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage example

```
scala> val x = MySing("hello")
x: MySing = MySing@232b0a52

scala> x.var1
res0: String = hello

scala> val y = MySing("hola")
y: MySing = MySing@232b0a52

scala> y.var1
res1: String = hello // are you sure this is sensible?
```

However, it still looks kind of ugly: you're creating a singleton with a parameter, consequently ignoring every argument passed to the `apply` method after the first invocation. Ugh!

You may want to rethink your design (and forget about `null`)

Comment: I have to agree about rethinking the design. This is an unfortunate combination of Singleton and Factory. Either you create the Singleton or you use a Factory to return a Singleton. Trying to do both is just ... wrong.