# How to pass a parameter to a lazy val

Tags: scala

I have a scenario where I want to pass a parameter when accessing a lazy value. The example below should explain the problem. Can someone recommend the best way to achieve this?

Thanks
Des

```
class A(test: Boolean) {

}

object A {

  lazy val a = new A(???)

  def apply(test: Boolean) = a(test)
}
```

Can of course be achieved using var and Option but wondering if there is a better way:

```
class A(test: Boolean) {

}

object A {

  var a: Option[A] = None

  def apply(test: Boolean) = a match {
    case Some(sa) => sa
    case None => 
      a = Some(new A(test))
      a.get
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the type to `a`:

```
class A(test: Boolean) { }

object A {

  lazy val a: A.type = A

  def apply(test: Boolean): A = a(test)
}
```

Although I don't see the point to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

The companion `object` is a singleton, so initializing its constant values (`val` and `lazy val`) using an external parameter doesn't really make sense.

If you need a different value for every instance, then move the `lazy val` to the class as such

```
class A(test: Boolean) {
    lazy val a = test
}
```

Otherwise just use a `def`

```
object A {
    def a(test: Boolean) = new A(test)
    def apply(test: Boolean) = a(test)
}
```

Comment: I probably haven't explained the context well. I want a singleton instance of A. But the instance needs an initialization parameter and should not be created at start up. This is why I am creating the instance lazily through the object. Is there a better approach?

Comment: A singleton with parameters is not a singleton. Are you sure you need a singleton in the first place?

Comment: @user7907 could this be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168908/use-nullable-instead-of-option/25169407#25169407